# Genetic Algorithm in .Net - Variable Chromosomes - Alien Spaceship Scenario

Tags: c#, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, heuristics, genetic-programming

**I want to implement a genetic algorithm that write programs, trying to resolve a particular problem.**

The 'program' is no more than a list of functions that will be evaluated by a fitness function, so I could know what is the best 'program'. The sequence does not metter for me, will not affect the fitness evaluation.

The **BIG CATCH** that I'm trying to figure out is that, the list of functions called should be variable, like a **variable cromossomes number**. 
I have functions that NEED to be called, with variable parameters, and functions that COULD (optional) be called, with variable parameters as well.

I already found those great GA frameworks, but Im really new to genetic programming, and I don't know what is the best framework to use for this problem:

- https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp
- https://dev.heuristiclab.com
- http://evolute-csharp.sourceforge.net/

**So, imagine this problem:**

- In an open field, like a 2d space, a **alien spaceship** need to go from point A to point B in the shortest time possible. But the program does not know where is point B.
- You can imagine the open field as a grid, like a chess board, but larger (100X100).
- The open field can have obstacles. The spaceship should try to avoid.
- The program MUST do some functions, like to choose the model of the spaceship and to fill up with gas.
- Then the spaceship can execute functions like **go front, back, left and right**.
- The spaceship can also use **hyper-speed**, that works like an transport to any point in the grid.
- The optional functions can be called more than one time, but would be great if this worked like a type of mutation, that works only 5% of times.
- All the functions and parameters used will affect the fitness evaluation.
- Order of the functions does not affect the fitness evaluation.

For better undertanding, if I could describe my INPUT as a JSON, it would be something like this:

```
{
    "FixedFunctions":[
        {"Name":"ChooseModel", "Parameters":[{"Name":"Type", "MinValue":1, "MaxValue":5,"Step":1}]},
        {"Name":"FillUp", "Parameters":[{"Name":"Litters", "MinValue":1, "MaxValue":100,"Step":2}]}
        ]
    "OptionalFunctions":[
        {"Name":"GoFront", "Parameters":[{"Name":"Steps", "MinValue":1, "MaxValue":50,"Step":5}]},
        {"Name":"GoBack", "Parameters":[{"Name":"Steps", "MinValue":1, "MaxValue":50,"Step":2}]},
        {"Name":"GoRight", "Parameters":[{"Name":"Steps", "MinValue":1, "MaxValue":25,"Step":2}]},
        {"Name":"GoLeft", "Parameters":[{"Name":"Steps", "MinValue":1, "MaxValue":25,"Step":2}]},
        {"Name":"HyperTeleport", "Parameters":[
            {"Name":"PointX", "MinValue":1, "MaxValue":100,"Step":2},
            {"Name":"PointY", "MinValue":1, "MaxValue":100,"Step":2}]}
        ]
}
```

So the cromossome could be something simple, as something complex:

```
- [ChooseModel(1), FillUp(30), HyperTeleport(3,5), GoBack(50)]
- [ChooseModel(3), FillUp(60), HyperTeleport(20,50), GoRight(2)]
- [ChooseModel(4), FillUp(40), GoFront(10), GoRight(2), GoLeft(30), GoBack(80), HyperTeleport(20,30), GoRight(5)]
...
```

So here I ask for help. What is the best way to resolve my problem? 
All examples I have found talk about fixed size cromossomes, but in my problem I have a variable number of options. Would be awesome to use Heuristiclab, as I could pause and continue, as see the operations hapening.

Thank you very much if you read until here!!!

Sorry for the long post. 'O'

Comment: Isn't possible use for this purpose "conventional" algorithm like A*, Breadth first search, depth first search.... ?

Comment: I think I could, but there is a lot of possibilities for my functions and their parameters. Would not be possible to visit every single node. This is why im thinking about genetic programming. The survival of the fittest. Could I do something similar with BFS DFS?

Comment: Probably not, but for path finding mission will be these algorithms better than genetic algorithm, so you can use some from these algorithms for pathfinding and genetic algorithm for remaining tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good tutorial on a machine learning implementation in javascript which guides rockets around an obstacle. It's pretty much exactly what you're trying to achieve with your project  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGz7mv2vD6g

It explains in details how to set up the evolution of the rockets path based on fitness. The algorithm adds values to an array which are the  steps the rockets take to avoid the obstacle.

Every round, the path arrays of each rocket are updated based on the the ones that were most successful last round. Over time the paths improve.

Comment: Very nice tutorial. After saw this video I'm thinking in developing my own genetic engine, just like Daniel does, but in c# and focused on my problem. I just don't know what would be the best way to randomize every single parameter (functions and their parameters). Should I generate X random chromossomes, with variable and random genes (parameters)?  Would not be better to check if the random chromosome was not already evaluated, and if so, ask for another random chromossome? Thanks!